# TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined and $resource is undefined in second post request

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

$resource is defined in the first call of angular services. But when its call for the second time it give the following error;

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

Checked on the $resource before the .post is called. It returns the **undefined**, which means $resource getting undefined before it getting used before second time.

What will be route cause on this? and any tips on resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because your defined $resource getting overridden. Have solved this by defining $resouce only if its not defined.

if(angular.isUndefined(resource))
 //define your resource